Matching number of lines
Follow the path of the shape, starting from the upper left all the way to the upper right, and tell me the answer to this puzzle. And please be honest!
        ↓
  — — — — — — — — — —                                       — — — — — — — — — —                  
                  →  |                                     |
                  →  |                                     |←
                      |                                     |                                    
                      |                                     |
                      |                                     |
                      |                                     |
                      |                                     | ←
                      |                                     |
                       \                                   /
                        \                                 /
                         \                               /
                          \                             /
                           \                           /                            
                        →  \                         /
                             \            ↓          / ←        
                              \ — — — — — — — — — — / ←

Note: There's a minor correction needed to find the answer. You'll definitely see what I mean once you understand how to approach the puzzle.

Is the fact that the amount of spaces before a "→" or a "←" is different important?

@WOWOW No, not important, only to which one they point to

Well,

 I've no idea.

How did I come to such conclusion?

 The only thing we have in the diagram are dashed lines, of three different kinds. If we follow the line segments, we can see that. the first, fourth and seventh are HORIZONTAL, the second and sixth are VERTICAL, and the third and fifth are DIAGONAL. Each of the segments contains as many dashes as letters in the corresponding word.

So how do we extract?

 If we pick the letters in the corresponding dashes, writing the words following the line, we get: horIzontal (I), VErtical (VE), diagoNal (N), horizOntal (O), DIagonal (DI), vErticAl (EA), horizontal.

Putting everything together,

 I'VE NO DIEA

Oh wait,

 There's a minor correction needed to find the answer.

Suggesting that we should

 Exchange the positions of D and I to get the answer.


Great job! The idea behind the figure was that it resembled the text version of the -emoji (just without the "head")

Yeah no, that went totally over my own head swoosh

This answer doesn't explain why certain dashes are offset.

@msh210 I just assumed they were artifacts due to the space occupied by the arrows. Like, different character lengths so the dashes don't line up correctly.

@ArturoVialArqueros but the asker deliberately formatted the ASCII art in a monospace font. So there are no differing character widths. (At least that's how it appears for me. If it appears otherwise for him/her, then he/she should've realized that different people will see the characters with different widths, and not relied on the width he/she saw.)
